# Very slow `hg clone` for big bitbucket repo

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I can add two files (16 MB for each) to empty repository and push it to bitbucket.org in 10 seconds. But cloning the same repo from bitbucket takes about 3 minutes.

This is the normal behavior or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Upload and download speeds of your Internet connection may differ.  In case of ADSL they are [always different](https://superuser.com/questions/914/why-upload-rates-are-lower-than-download-rates-in-normal-internet-connections) and I suppose other technologies have this property too.  However, the upload speed usually lower than download speed and you have absolutely opposite situation.

I think the reason is bitbucket.org has a much more clients who download content than clients who upload content.  That is, browsing bitbucket.org is much more common action than commits.  It's bandwidth simply too low to make download as fast as upload.

You can check that it is pure bandwidth problem by cloning repository without update:

```
hg clone -U ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/repo
```

Comment: Not 100% related and I don't disagree with your answer but I find cloning git repos from bitbucket to be 10 to 100 times faster than cloning hg repos.  This post and the comments would seem to support that: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/161164/why-is-hg-pull-so-slow

Comment: For many, the incantation that solves the problem is to add the `--uncompressed` flag to `hg clone`. So, for your example,

`hg clone --uncompressed ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/repo`

Answer (score 1):

I had a simlilar Issue with bitbucket and git. 
After all, what **solve my Issue** was to **force ssh** in ~/.ssh/config **to use IPv4** with this line:

```
AddressFamily inet
```

Hope this helps someone.